# How to combine toggle on off with http.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try make toggle with bootstrap toggle and give som function http.get if toggle click on or off. But i have some trouble  if on clicked it work but if off clicked it didn't work. My code like this

```
<input id="toggle-two" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-width="100">
        <script>
          $(function() {
                        $('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle({
                          on: 'Lock',
                          off: 'Unlock'
                        }).on('change', function() {
                          $.ajax({ 
                            url: 'http://localhost/web.php?tN=rlock&f12=123456789',
                            data: { checked: $(this).prop('checked') },
                            success: function() {
                              console.log('Lock');
                            }
                            });
                          }).off('change', function() {
                          $.ajax({ 
                            url: 'http://localhost/web.php?tN=runlock&f12=123456789',
                            data: { checked: $(this).prop('checked') },
                            success: function() {
                              console.log('Unlock');
                            }
                            });
                          });
                        });
        </script>
```

i don't know how to fix it, please helpme to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<input id="toggle-two" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-width="100">
<script>
  $(function() {
     $('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle({
       on: 'Lock',
       off: 'Unlock'
     }).on('change', function() {
       var Checked_or_not = this.checked,  // check if checked or unchecked
           tN = Checked_or_not ? 'rlock' : 'runlock';  // if checked return 'rlock' if unchecked return 'runlock' for tN in url 
       $.ajax({ 
           url: 'http://localhost/web.php?tN='+ tN +'&f12=123456789',  // add tN in url
           data: { checked:  Checked_or_not }, 
           success: function() {
                      console.log('Lock');
                    }
        });
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @RizkaNugroho glad it helped . Have a great day :-)